# Dynamically add content in the multiselect dropdown in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have some doubt on multiple select in dropdown with checkbox. i want to dynamically add the content in drop down whenever i upload a image in jquery.How to refresh dropdown with new data?

```
$('#listImage').multiselect({});
```

once i get the new data i tried to refresh the multiselect but that throws error.

```
 $("#widgetSettingsForm select[multiple]").multiselect('rebuild');
```

Uncaught Error: no such method 'rebuild' for multiselect widget instance(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use refresh instead of rebuild : http://jsfiddle.net/o7xf9awv/1/

```
$("#test001").multiselect('refresh');
```

```js
$("#test001").multiselect({
  header: false,
  noneSelectedText: "Select"
});
var count = 2;
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#test001").append('<option value="option5">Option ' + ++count + '</option>');
  $("#test001").multiselect('refresh');
});

$("#remove").click(function() {
  $("#test001 option:last").remove();
  $("#test001").multiselect('refresh');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/1.10/src/jquery.multiselect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/1.10/jquery.multiselect.css">
<input type="button" id="add" value="add" />
<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove last" />
<br/>
<select id="test001" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How to remove something dynamically?

Comment: Check the updated code. You can write your custom remove on the same lines.